# Read String and count the number vowels using scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Write a procedure called count_vowel that counts the number of vowels (a, e, i, o, u) in any given strings.

so far I have this....

```
 (define (count_vowel (str)
                 (char-set-fold (count_vowel (ch i) (if (vowel? ch) (+ i 1) i)) 0 str))
```

but I get this error...
"#%plain-lambda: not an identifier in : (str) "

I need to use DrRacket with R5RS as the lanuage.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define (count-vowel str)
    (char-set-fold (lambda (ch i) 
                       (if (vowel? ch) 
                           (+ i 1)
                           i))
                   0 (string->char-set str)))
```

Comment: I would put that last argument on a newline to be consistent :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `define` is wrong.

It should be:

```
(define (count_vowel str)
   .... )
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original solution, notice that the indentation of the second line is wrong. Whenever the indentation is wrong, it is a sign that there is an parenthesis mistake somewhere. The exact mistake is pointed out in the other answers.

Since `char-set-fold` is a srfi function, I thought, a pure R5RS solution
would be in order. I mistakenly thought that `filter` was part of R5RS and thus
the following were meant to be a short solution. It turned out that `filter` wasn't part of R5RS...

```
#lang r5rs

(define vowels (string->list "aeiouyæøå"))

(define (vowel? c)
  (member c vowels))

(define (filter p xs)
  (define (more) (filter p (cdr xs)))
  (cond
    ((null? xs)    '())
    ((p (car xs))  (cons (car xs) (more)))
    (else          (more))))


(define (count-vowels s)
  (length (filter vowel? (string->list s))))

(display (count-vowels "foobarbaz"))
(newline)
```

Comment: okay that makes sense, so why can't i call the (count_vowel " ") function again to test another work? It tells me it is undefined; cannot reference undefined identifier?

Comment: it works when i do (display (count-vowels "code")) so in order to check another string i need to do dispaly?

Comment: I used an `-` not an `_` in the name `count-vowels`.

In the REPL you can just write `(count-vowels " ")` but if you put it into the program, then the `#lang r5rs` doesn't automatically prints the result. That's  why I inserted an explicit `display`.